# What is this Front End Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, frontend

I'm building a website and have been looking over various front end designs.  I've seen a number of modern sites with interactive vertical sections.  Meaning as you scroll down the page the user is presented with new related content.

This website has an example of the design i'm looking at, please ignore the content i won't be using that in my site. I'm speaking more about how it has various discreet sections as you scroll down the page.

http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/

### The Question

Does this design have a specific name? i'm interested in learning more about it and finding better examples but am having a hard time finding sites specifically about implementing this. A design name I could look into more would be perfect and any resources on building out this style specifically would also be welcome.

### Best Answer

in talking to people i think the best answer is that this is a scrolling site design.  this seems a bit simple but it doesn't quite fit any of the more specific designs.  I selected parallax, because it's results led me to better google seraches and examples for what i was trying to specify.  I'll also share some of the good examples i have found in my searches.

### Edit

Having done more research, and in working on a specific site with this design pattern.  I've found a better answer.  These are called scrolling sites, also known as single page sites.  There are also a number of JS libraries like this [one](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage), to help you build the  auto-scroll functionality.

useful scrolling ui tool : http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

interesting content, and good parallax site : http://kennedyandoswald.com/#!/jfk-bio

Comment: infinite scroll?  http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to Parallax Scrolling:

http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html

Answer (score 2):

It's called "infinite scroll".

Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1309/

Comment: hmm, my interest is more in the discrete sections, maybe that just styling as opposed to a formal design.  but the content would all load up front, and it would have a proper footer like a traditional site, but the content would be broken into sections like it is with infinite scroll.

I'm wondering if there is something more specific for partitioning the sections?  tho you certainly get bonus points for referencing xkcd.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's scrollspy certainly has some of that idea built in, where you can define sections that trigger additional actions: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy.

While their thing applies specifically to menus being updated, i'm sure the events could be used to trigger other things as well.